# How to call a function taking no arguments from an instance?

Tags: haskell

Assume, you have a class:

```
class AClass a where
  func:: Int

instance AClass SomeTree where
  func = 0

instance AClass Double where
  func = 1
```

How do I call the function func?

Comment: `neutral :: Int`, should work, since information both is gathered from the input type and output type.

Comment: Using `(+)` here however will introduce a problem, since `(+) a b = a + b` will result in infinite recursion.

Comment: you are right. Stupid example. What if Neutral would give a static type back (for all groups the same type) How would I call neutral then?

Comment: I changed the question acordingly.

Comment: There's no such thing as a function that takes no arguments. `func` here is just an `Int`. Use it like any other `Int`. The bigger issue is that you can't define `func` to have a type that doesn't involve `a` in some way.

Comment: func:: {} -> Int ???

I mean even if you assume it is just an Int. How do you use it?

Comment: You appear to be trying to define `func` like a class attribute in an object-oriented language.

Comment: @TVSuchty: Then you can use `TypeApplications`: `func @Double`.

Comment: Okay, I could change the definition of func from Int -> Int
where func is constant but not the same for each instance
Quote:
Then you can use TypeApplications: func @ Double
What is that?

Comment: My example is not off world. For example you could define a class Finite b, which would have function enumerated, where all possible values are listed...

Comment: You can add `{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}` to your file, which enables a new `@` notation for providing type arguments.  Then, you can write `func @SomeTree`, which will yield 0, or `func @Double`, which will yield 1.  See [the docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-TypeApplications)

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: What you have now *isn't* legal, so it doesn't make sense to ask how to use `func`: it cannot be defined.

Comment: I am sorry chepner. I think I just used in deed the concept of interfaces in OO - Languages to much. I did not realize this was not legal. However, the answer given is now satisfiying to me

Could you explain why it is not legal in an abstract sense?

Comment: The purpose of a type class is to provide ad hoc polymorphism. As such, all members of a class need to be polymorphic. A monomorphic member such as `func` in your example has no business being in a type class.

Comment: Would func() not be polymorphic if you use it in an abstract class (C++) ? What do you mean by monomorphic?
Clearly, func() does something different in a different Typeclass.

Comment: A preexisting example of a polymorphic value is `Nothing`: its type is `forall a. Maybe a`, and concrete monomorphic values include `Nothing :: Maybe Char`, `Nothing :: Maybe Int`, `Nothing :: Maybe [Double]`, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications #-}

class AClass a where
  func :: Int

instance AClass SomeTree where
  func = 0

instance AClass Double where
  func = 1

foo :: Int
foo = func @SomeTree + func @Double

{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, UnicodeSyntax #-}

bar :: ∀ a . AClass a => a -> Int
bar _ = func @a
```

Comment: What magic does the bar Type constraint do?
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: `∀ a .` is just what you implicitly have in functions like `sum :: Num a => [a] -> a`, which is actually shorthand for `sum :: ∀ a . Num a => [a] -> a`. The difference is that the explicit `∀` (aka `forall`) brings the `a` into scope in such a way that it can be used _in the function body_, as here with `func @a`.